# How to use model __call__ on list of various shaped numpy arrays?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use the Keras `model()` way of predicting. The `model.predict()` way works fine but I need a faster way of doing predictions with my trained model.

Here is the error when I do `model(pred_emb)` :

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <tensorflow.python.saved_model.function_deserialization.RestoredFunction object at 0x7fd0147e5d30> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (4 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1000, 224, 224, 3), dtype=uint8)
    * False
    * False
    * 0.99
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (4 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * True
    * False
    * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (4 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * True
    * True
    * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 3:
  Positional arguments (4 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * False
    * True
    * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 4:
  Positional arguments (4 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * False
    * False
    * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

where `pred_emb` has the following properties:

[image]

**What I've tried so far:**

- Trained another model without including `pred_emb[3]` so the input features were only  `pred_emb[0]`, `pred_emb[1]`, and `pred_emb[2]`. The `model()` way of predicting worked. I think the `pred_emb[3]` which contains 1000 image numpy values of shape `(224,224,3)` causes the error when I do `model(pred_emb)`. I already tried to reshape it and used ragged tensors to convert it into tensor shape to resolve the error but none of what I've attempted worked.

Thank you in advance for your guidance and help.

Comment: Apparently your 4th argument `0.99`, should instead be `TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')`, whatever that is.

Comment: @mapf I do not understand why it's 0.99 when what I have is a (224,224,3) dimension - elements in the 4th argument.

Comment: I see. But without the actual code where you make the call it's impossible to find the error.

Comment: @mapf I managed to fix the error by typecasting 4th argument from uint8 to float32. But prediction using `model()` got slower vs untypecased on model.predict(). Do you mind if I ask your thoughts or tips on this? Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Unfortunately I don't know why this would slow things down (considerably). Sorry. I'm pretty sure though someone on here will know.